# Liferay 6.2 and JSF/Primefaces integration issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to build a portlet in Liferay (v6.2 CE), for using primefaces v5.1 for UI controls.

If not mistaken, for doing so, the Java Faces implementation is required by Liferay, so here is my ivy.xml (external jars):

```
...
<dependencies defaultconf="default">
    <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
    <dependency name="jsf-api" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
    <dependency name="jsf-impl" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />

    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-api" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.1.0-ga1" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.1.0-ga1" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.1.0-ga1" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-util" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.1.0-ga1" />

    <dependency name="primefaces" org="org.primefaces" rev="5.1" />

    <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-api" rev="2.4" />
    <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-core" rev="2.4" />

    <dependency org="dom4j" name="dom4j" rev="1.6.1"/>

    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="3.6.6.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-c3p0" rev="3.6.6.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="4.2.0.Final" />
    <dependency org="c3p0" name="c3p0" rev="0.9.1.2" />
    <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.13"/>
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.1" />

    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-tools" rev="3.2.4.GA" />
    <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging-api" rev="1.1" />

</dependencies>
```

This seem to work in previous liferay versions. However using this combination of Liferay version & primefaces/JSF i receive in my log the following error:

```
13 Οκτ 2015 10:50:59 πμ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Coppa Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory. 
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1010)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:342)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseBaseImpl.<init>(BridgePhaseBaseImpl.java:102)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseCompat_1_2_Impl.<init>(BridgePhaseCompat_1_2_Impl.java:27)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseCompat_2_0_Impl.<init>(BridgePhaseCompat_2_0_Impl.java:38)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseCompat_2_2_Impl.<init>(BridgePhaseCompat_2_2_Impl.java:29)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.<init>(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:66)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseFactoryImpl.getBridgeRenderPhase(BridgePhaseFactoryImpl.java:49)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:110)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:656)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:362)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1233)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:655)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:138)
at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:125)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.render(PortletRenderer.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:452)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePageImpl.java:284)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:113)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:124)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePageUtil.java:69)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:556)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:302)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:405)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:200)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:95)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:178)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:549)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:526)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:156)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:267)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
10:50:59,551 ERROR [http-bio-8082-exec-8][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory. 
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1010)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:342)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseBaseImpl.<init>(BridgePhaseBaseImpl.java:102)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseCompat_1_2_Impl.<init>(BridgePhaseCompat_1_2_Impl.java:27)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseCompat_2_0_Impl.<init>(BridgePhaseCompat_2_0_Impl.java:38)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseCompat_2_2_Impl.<init>(BridgePhaseCompat_2_2_Impl.java:29)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.<init>(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:66)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseFactoryImpl.getBridgeRenderPhase(BridgePhaseFactoryImpl.java:49)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:110)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

So i guess that something is wrong with JSF integration with liferay? What the message:

```
Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory.
```

can mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit: This answer is now long out-of-date. Go to https://liferayfaces.org to determine the correct versions of the Liferay Faces JARs that you need.

There is no Liferay Faces version `4.1.0-ga1`.* Because you are using JSF 2.1 and Liferay 6.2, you should use Liferay Faces [`3.2.5-ga6`](https://www.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-liferay-faces-4-x-3-x-2-x-ga6-released) according to the [Liferay Faces Version Scheme](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/understanding-the-liferay-faces-version-scheme). You should also upgrade to the latest Mojarra version: [`2.1.29-04`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.29-04/).

<sup>*There is a `4.2.5-ga6` version, but that version is [designed to be used with JSF 2.2 and Liferay 6.2 in Tomcat only](https://www.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-liferay-faces-4-x-3-x-2-x-ga6-released).</sup>